# "She's the author of" or "She's author of"? - which one is correct?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

What's the difference in the usage of the article "the" with the word "author"? Why is the article "the" left in the second sentence?

> **She's the author of** "The Power of Glamour," "The Future and Its
>   Enemies" and "The Substance of Style."
>
> **She's author of** the new book,
>   “The Intimidation Game: How the Left is Silencing Free Speech.”

Answer (score 7):

The word "author" is a singular countable noun, and in the majority of cases [the definite article is used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she%20is%20author%20of%2Che%20is%20author%20of%2C%20she%20is%20the%20author%20of%2C%20he%20is%20the%20author%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20is%20author%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20author%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20is%20the%20author%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20the%20author%20of%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

However, in English the definite article [is sometimes omitted](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/75384/2127) if the word designates a unique role or task:

> John is captain of the team.

I guess that the same pattern applies to

> John is author of the book.

After all, being the author of a book is quite a unique role. If the book was written by you only, it's the same as if the team was led by you only.

---

Related:

- [Is there a missing definite article before caliph in 'the group's leader, XYZ, as (the) caliph'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27182/2127)
- [Articles before professions names: “Ms. Smith, public health nurse, was born…”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75366/articles-before-professions-names-ms-smith-public-health-nurse-was-born)
- [Article usage in a noun clause: “Tim Courtney, (a?) (the?) chief investment officer of Exencial Wealth Advisors, said..”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/75682/2127)
- [Zero article before emperor in “You will not be emperor”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/51793/2127)
- [He was state champion and national record holder](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31027/2127)

Comment: I wonder what happened in the 1920's and 30's that caused such a large temporary increase in "he is author of" relative to the rest of the graph.

Answer (score -1):

John is the author of the book. [there is only one author of that book]

Reason: When there is only one thing, the article is used. In your case, there are three separate things, each of which is unique and the only one of its kind.

compare that to: John is an author. [among many, many authors in the world]