# Zero article before emperor in "You will not be emperor"

Tags: articles, zero-article

[Emperor](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/emperor) is a countable noun according to the Cambridge dictionary. Why the zero article is used in the following sentence?

```
You will not be emperor. (Gladiator)
```

Comparing to the similar construction in which the definite article is used

```
You will be a god-king. (300 Rise of Empire)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The definite article "the" was missing](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/the-definite-article-the-was-missing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Predicate nominals that are unique titles, in the sense of positions being held by one person, can take zero article or a definite article as shown in 31(a) and 31(b)....
>
> 31
> a. John is managing editor of the *St. Louis Post-Dispatch.*
> b. John is the managing editor of the *St. Louis Post-Dispatch.*

Cowan, Ron. (2008). *The Teacher's Grammar of English with Answers: A Course Book and Reference Guide.* Cambridge, UK: Cambridge University Press. p. 218.