# Articles before profession names: "Ms. Smith, public health nurse, was born..."

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, appositives

I know that, in general, we use an article before a name of a profession.

For instance:

> He is a doctor.

But should we put an article in the following cases?

> Mr. Smith, a doctor, works…
>
> Ms. Smith, public health nurse, was born…
>
> Mr. Smith, the third chief of justice of the Supreme Court, did…

Comment: In *Mr. Smith, [whatever-he-is], [yada-yada-yada]*, the part [whatever-he-is] is not a part of *Mr. Smith*, i.e., it's not "Mr. Smith whatever-he-is", but the "whatever-he-is" is like a renamer of "Mr. Smith". That's why we have commas both before and after [whatever-he-is].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a missing definite article before caliph in 'the group's leader, XYZ, as (the) caliph'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/is-there-a-missing-definite-article-before-caliph-in-the-groups-leader-xyz-a)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, we usually use the indefinite article when we describe someone's occupation in a [construction with **be**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)):

> He *is* **a** doctor.

But when we name a unique role or task, we either use **the** or omit the article altogether:

> John *is* (the) captain of the team.

Since the team has only one captain, we are free to omit **the**.

When we put the person (he, John) and the "describing element" side by side (*[apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)*), the same principle applies:

> John, (the) captain of the team, said: "We are going to win this match".

---

So,

> Mr. Smith, **a** doctor, works...

... is okay.

But since "public health nurse" is not a unique role or task, we should use **a**:

> Ms. Smith, **a** public health nurse, was born..

---

"Chief Justice of the Supreme Court" is a unique role, so **the** is omissible:

> Mr. Smith, (the) Chief Justice of the Supreme Court, did..

But we do not drop **the** if it stands before an *[ordinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics))* that describes a person's position among other persons of the same rank, hence

> Mr. Smith, **the** third Chief Justice of the Supreme Court, did..

---

Reference:

- Quirk et al., "[A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language)", Unit 5.37, "Nonreferring uses of the indefinite article".
- The same book, Unit 5.42, "The zero article with definite meaning: Noun phrases in a copular relation"

---

P.S. If you're interested, in Unit 5.37 Quirk et al. start off by describing noun phrases in *[copular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics))* relationship (constructions of the type "Mr. Smith *is* a carpenter", where '*is*' is a *copular verb*). Then they point out that you can omit the indefinite article in the following "*as-constructions*":

> her duties as (a) hostess
>   my appointment as (a) lecturer
>   Jung as (a) thinker

It's interesting why exactly we can omit **a** in these cases. The authors write "compare with '*unique role*', Unit 5.42". Could "hostess, lecturer, thinker" be understood as "unique roles" in specific contexts? I don't know. Article usage is hellishly complex.

Comment: Thank you very much for complete answer. It is very conclusive for me, but I have met the expression "Lillian D. Wald, public health nurse and __________, was born in Cincinnati Ohio, in 1867" in the TOEFL test. Are there any exceptions to this rule?

Comment: Regarding omission of the definite article - we sometimes do that when something is a title, or treated like one.  For example, "He is captain of the team", or "She is hostess of the party."  When we elide the explanatory bit (*of the team* or *of the party*) we still omit the article.  I don't have a good reference for this, though!

Comment: @arsast - good point! I'm at a loss. Maybe I've overlooked something.

Comment: @arsast - **[in this PDF from the NY Public Library](https://www.nypl.org/sites/default/files/blog_attachments/wald.pdf)**, written apparently by a native English speaker, a similar sentence uses "**a** public health nurse" (see page 3).

Comment: @arsast - if your TOEFL page **[is from this book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=OhnEAwAAQBAJ&hl=ru&source=gbs_navlinks_s)**, then it might be a typo, since the authors are not native English speakers. We've been discussing the question in the chat, and Damkerng found **[this excerpt from this book](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26030147#26030147)** with your sentence.