# Article usage in a noun clause: "Tim Courtney, (a?) (the?) chief investment officer of Exencial Wealth Advisors, said.."

Tags: articles, appositives

I am struggling with using articles in noun clauses. I have seen some examples where an articles is omitted when the following noun is not even uncountable. For example:

"Tim Courtney, **chief investment officer of Exencial Wealth Advisors**, said: 'We're stockpiling commodities and demand is not picking up. It's kind of a depressing market.'"

Would it be correct if I write " Time Courtney, **a** chief investment officer of Exencial Wealth Advisors,..." with an article. I do not believe the word "officer" is uncountable.

Another example to further explain my problem: 
Mr. Smith, a teacher at Lincoln high school, has a phD degree in math.
or
Mr. Smith, teacher at Lincoln high school, has a phD degree in math.

Which one is grammatically correct? Or are both acceptable? or they simply carry different meanings.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Or would it be ok if I write :Tim Courney, the chief investment officer of Exencial Wealth Advisors..." with the word "the"?

Comment: Related: **[Articles before professions names: “Ms. Smith, public health nurse, was born…”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75366/articles-before-professions-names-ms-smith-public-health-nurse-was-born)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.

"Tim Courtney, chief investment officer of ... " sounds more authoritative, since we don't know whether he's the *only* chief investment officer, or one of the *two* chief investment officers, etc.

"Tim Courtney, a chief investment officer of ... " lets you know that he's one of ***many***, which right away undermines his authority.