# Missing an article before professions

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I’ve met some cases of not using an article **A** before a profession.
One of them was in “Friends” when Monica said: “I’ll be coordinator”
Here I thought it was just her mistake in speaking English.
But then I met the same case in Peppa Pig when Madame Gazelle asked: “Who wants to be shopkeeper?”
In both cases, there should be an article **a** before the profession: a coordinator, a shopkeeper according to the rules.
So, what is this then? Why don’t they use the article here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Articles before profession names: "Ms. Smith, public health nurse, was born..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75366/articles-before-profession-names-ms-smith-public-health-nurse-was-born) I realize the question isn't exactly the same, but there is a very good answer to that question I think will help you.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, there is an answer to my question there 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your knowledge of 'the rules' is incomplete. There does not have to be an article before the title of a unique job or position. You could use a definite article ('the') but you don't have to.

After his mother died, Charles was king.

Trump was president from 2016 to 2020.

We are playing a game of pirates and I will be captain.

My uncle is head doctor at the city hospital.

> An article is unnecessary in official job titles if there is only one
> person holding this position at any given time (i.e. Justin Trudeau
> was (the) Prime Minister of Canada during the COVID-19 crisis.).

[Using the Zero Article (Allison Library, Regent College, Vancouver)](https://allisonlibrary.regent-college.edu/sites/default/files/Article%20Usage.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer  Sure, my knowledge of the rules is incomplete. That’s why I am asking here  I asked one teacher of English who is native speaker and he said: “We just say that but he can’t say why”. So I appreciate your explanation. Where can I find this rule? I’d like to explore this more. As I understand, we could use the definite article instead of zero article here?

Comment: @Natalia -just do Google searches for 'zero article before unique job title or position'. Also see my addition above.