# 'king of the lionfish' or 'the king of the lionfish'

Tags: articles

I came across the headline "Becoming king of the lionfish to save the ocean" from [CNN](http://www.greatbigstory.com/stories/becoming-king-to-save-the-ocean/?xrs=CNNHP) but grammatically I guess *the king of the lionfish* seems better correct as *the king* is *of the lionfish*. Is it grammatically correct not to use *the* in this case, or does it give different meaning with or without the article?

Comment: "King" is a unique role, and [in such cases we often omit articles](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/is-there-a-missing-definite-article-before-caliph-in-the-groups-leader-xyz-a?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @prosseek - All is revealed [here](http://www.englishgrammartutor.com/articles.htm)!

Comment: Your question title does not match what you are asking about in the question body.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - theoretically, the database of StackExchange will survive longer than many of the links to external resources, so someday it will be a dead link. I usually quote excerpts into my answers or hyperlink to Wikipedia, which may stay shipshape for long, I hope. (0:

Comment: @AlanCarmack The article (forgive me...) is dense, and the question has other issues, but your point is well-taken. Haven't looked for a good Wikipedia source. That's sound advice.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't really matter that much, although yes, ***the*** king would be slightly more grammatical, because the definite article is used before singular and plural nouns when the noun is specific or particular.

Comment: Can you please explain why it would be more grammatical.