# What is the difference between 'the President’ and 'President'?

Tags: vocabulary, definite-article

1. If I were the President, I would make everyone happy.
2. If I were President, I would make everyone happy.

Could you tell me the differences between the sentences?

I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @ColleenV That is not the same and provides no definite guidance, in my opinion.

Comment: @Lambie It could use a better answer, but it’s essentially the same question.

Comment: @ColleenV I disagree. That one asks why there is no "the" and not what the difference would be with a the and without one.

Comment: Actually, this is the one I was looking for and couldn’t find (until now that is) https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27182/9161

Answer (score 0):

- If I were the President, I would make everyone happy.

The specific one in office now.

- If I were president, I would make everyone happy.

A generic idea not referring to the president in office now.

[US news organizations capitalize the President, for the US president but it is not really necessary. It is a style choice.]