# Articles as manager/as a manager

Tags: articles, zero-article, as

- I'd be happy to see Jim *as manager*.
- That might be a little confusing because they know me *as manager*.
- We will work with him on the issue, in his capacity *as manager* of the company.
- But *as manager*, you can hire your own staff.

**Why isn't any article added after "as" and before the noun?** in comparison with below examples:

- *As a police officer*, violence is part of my everyday life.
- I'm not here *as a friend*.

**Is there any specific grammar rule for such phrases?**

Comment: There are several similar questions both at this site (e.g., https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/is-there-a-missing-definite-article-before-caliph-in-the-groups-leader-xyz-a) and on ELU (e.g., https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305487/indefinite-article-and-preposition-as).

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the precise rule, but I notice that in all of the top examples with no article, and in some more I've thought up, the article "the" could be used without changing the meaning:

- I'd be happy to see Jim as *the* manager.
- That might be a little confusing because they know me as *the* manager.
- With this class, I think Sue would do better as *(the)* teacher than as *(the)* teacher's assistant.

In your two cases where *zero article* is clearly wrong, "the" would also be wrong:

- As *the* police officer, violence is part of my everyday life.
- I'm not here as *the* friend.

Comment: It is an oddity of _as_ that when it precedes an office or role, it does not need an article: _as president_, _as executor_, _as commander in chief_. It's not clear to me what the limits of this construction are: it usually requires that the role is unique, at least in the context. So if you're talking about somebody who is a teacher, you can't normally say _as teacher_; but if you're talking about the relationship between the teacher and their pupil or pupils you then could say _as teacher_, meaning "as the one who is the teacher in this relationship".